# Prevent .stop() from stopping other animations

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have this little drop down arrow `<div>` that i want to move up when it's clicked, which works. But there's another animation on it which changes its opacity and uses the jQuery function `.stop()`. The problem is that whenever i hover over it during the sliding animation, the element stops dead in its tracks and doesn't finish the animation.

How do i solve this?

PS: if anyone has any suggestions on how to toggleclick two functions, i'd love to hear them, the one for hover seems a lot more convenient. Adding an attribute just for that is kind of lame.

EDIT: usable example: http://plnkr.co/edit/swuKbS3uM8G6stFnUT8U?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready for action!");


    // Dropdown icon hover

    $("#dropdownIcon").hover(function () {
        $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(500, 1);
        console.log("hovering");
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(500, 0.3);
        console.log("no longer hovering");
    });


    // Clicking on dropdown icon

    $("#dropdownIcon").on("click", function () {
        $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up");
        console.log("i clicked on the thing!");
        if ($(this).attr("data-click-state") == 1) {
            $(this).attr("data-click-state", 0);
            $(this).animate({bottom:"0"},1000);
            console.log("clicked once");
        } else {
            $(this).attr("data-click-state", 1);
            $(this).animate({bottom:"50%"},1000);
            console.log("clicked again");
        }
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/normalize.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Rmonik</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>
                RMONIK
            </h1>
            <div id="dropdownIcon" data-click-state="0">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>

        </header>

        <nav></nav>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css` at Question?, create plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: Not sure why that's necessary, it's literally just a `div` with id `#dropdownIcon` that is being moved around.

Comment: _"Not sure why that's necessary"_ To reproduce issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Done, but it doesn't make much sense without the CSS. I'm editing your plnkr now for a usable example: http://plnkr.co/edit/swuKbS3uM8G6stFnUT8U?p=preview

Comment: You want the sliding effect to proceed when element is hovered?

Comment: Yes. I want the two animations to be independent from each other. A possible solution is to just disable the hovering function altogether when the sliding is going on, since i don't need the opacity to change during the hover, but i'm not sure how to do that either...

Comment: jquery animations are always queued for any given element. it isn't possible for two separate animations to happen at the same time on the same element unless they're both started with a single call to .animate, effectively making them one. using css transitions and adding/removing classes would be a far simpler solution. the hover portion wouldn't even need a javascript event.

Comment: @KevinB _"jquery animations are always queued for any given element. it isn't possible for two separate animations to happen at the same time on the same element unless they're both started with a single call to .animate"_ Are you sure about this?

Comment: @guest271314 eh, i guess you could get around it if you specified a separate custom queue for it to use. but if you're just using the default fx queue, yeah only one will run at a time.

Comment: @KevinB http://plnkr.co/edit/lnCfTPh2k20foTOZ2Vbj?p=preview

Comment: @guest271314 http://plnkr.co/edit/B6VzySOzqGOkLzp520Ap?p=preview same idea

Comment: @KevinB Note, when options are passed as object to `.animate()`, `duration` should be property of object, else `duration` would not be recognized  http://plnkr.co/edit/iE4SEWYxmy5yzteu8rqL?p=preview

Comment: @KevinB That's also really cool, i like how the two animations are still separate. I'm gonna look into queues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `mouseover`, `mouseleave` events as named functions; use `.off()`, `complete` function of `.animate()` to re-attach `mouseover`, `mouseleave` events to element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready for action!");

  // Dropdown icon hover
  function handleMouseOver() {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
  }

  function handleMouseLeave() {
    $(this).fadeTo(500, 0.3)
  }

  function handleAnimationComplete() {
    $(this).on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
      .on("mouseleave", handleMouseLeave)
  }

  $("#dropdownIcon").on("mouseover", handleMouseOver)
    .on("mouseleave", handleMouseLeave);


  // Clicking on dropdown icon

  $("#dropdownIcon").on("click", function() {
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up");
    console.log("i clicked on the thing!");
    if ($(this).attr("data-click-state") == 1) {
      $(this).attr("data-click-state", 0);
      $(this).off("mouseover mouseleave")
        .animate({
          bottom: "0"
        }, 1000, handleAnimationComplete);
      console.log("clicked once");
    } else {
      $(this).attr("data-click-state", 1);
      $(this).off("mouseover mouseleave")
        .animate({
          bottom: "-200px"
        }, 1000, handleAnimationComplete);
      console.log("clicked again");
    }
  });

});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/qpZM7qRJIjcMebvSs7mB?p=preview

Comment: true, it will only stop the animation currently running, but that doesn't differentiate between it being the sliding animation or the opacity one. The problem here is that he's trying to perform two different animations seemingly at the same time, from two different events, but jquery isn't going to run them at the same time; they're going to be ran in sequence, so the whole idea isn't going to work anyway. css transitions would make this possible though.

Comment: @KevinB Not entirely certain what OP is trying to achieve? `.stop(false)` at first first function to `.hover()`, `.stop(true)` at second parameter to `.hover()` does not stop sliding effect. See version 2 of plnkr

Comment: I almost never see the animation on clicking in that plnkr, seems to be getting stopped by something.

Comment: I've included a plnkr with a more noticeable animation: http://plnkr.co/edit/swuKbS3uM8G6stFnUT8U?p=preview

Comment: if you move your mouse at all during the slide up/down, it all stops. but your fix does fix it.

Comment: That's amazing, thanks! Gonna take me a while to completely grasp it but it solved it :)